# Django settings issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

Can any one tell me what is the issue in finding the media directory.In the templates when i  say /media/images/logo.jpg It is unable to find the /media directory

The /media directory is in /home/project/myproject
Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue

I have the follwoing in my settings.py file

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/project/myproject/media/'


# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash. 
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

The following is in myproject.wsgi file

```
sys.path = ['/home/project/lib/python2.6/django/', '/home/project/lib/python2.6','/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages','/home/project/myproject'] + sys.path

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1):

But you've set `MEDIA_URL` to `''`! So why are you looking for images in `\media`?

If you want images to be in `\media`, you should set MEDIA_URL to that. Although you'll need to set `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to something else.

Comment: I have chnaged MEDIA_URL='the path' i.e,/media what else should i do.In my templates when i say /media/js/javascriptfile.It is unable to find it..

Answer (score 1):

MEDIA_ROOT is where files served at MEDIA_URL are resolved from. Users that are requesting static files can't hit your file path (MEDIA_ROOT), but they can request resources from a URL (MEDIA_URL). You need to define the MEDIA_URL, and you need to ensure that it is different to ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX.